# Postman - insert variable inside a test statement

Tags: postman, var

Let's take a regular test statement:

```
pm.test("response is ok", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

I need to customize the statement with a variable:

```
pm.test("response for Customer Number" + {{CustomerNumber}} + " is ok", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

Where CustomerNumber is a defined environment variable.

I have tried with {{$CustomerNumber}} but nothing seems to work, it throws an error.

Comment: remove your answers(which are actually not an answers) it unnecessarily deviating other answers from your question and mention whatever you want to say in the above post or in here comment section. Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly and follow the same in next posts

Comment: This is a great question with a simple answer. Please allow editing for better SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Works for me.

```
pm.test("response for Customer Number" + pm.environment.get("CustomerNumber") + " is ok", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

Comment: On my script executing your suggestion, the one you gave yesterday and the same as today gives me 'Unresolved variable':

pm.test("response for Customer Number " + pm.environment.get("path") + " is ok", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. I gave the wrong example.

I AM actually executing your suggestion, the one you gave yesterday and the same as today.

pm.test("response for Customer Number " + pm.environment.get("path") + " is ok", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
(Now I am copying directly from my source code)

Are you reading the variable value from a data input file in Collection Runner?

When I hover above the variable in the URL before opening Collection Runner, Postmans displays 'Unresolved variable'. The variable is populated after reading from the data input file.

Answer (score 0):

There are different [variable scopes](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/variables/#variable-scopes), so make sure you use the correct one.

```
pm.environment.get("variable_key");
pm.globals.get("variable_key");
pm.variables.get("variable_key");
pm.collectionVariables.get("variable_key");
```